# Addons 'update code' phase

Tags: engineyard

I'm looking into EY addon API.
The ocumentation mentions an optional 'Update Code' phase:
https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21288963-Extend-Engine-Yard-Cloud-with-Partner-Add-on-Services

1) What's included in this 'code update'? Am I guessing correctly that it's client libraries+code? E.g. if my application uses some datastorage addon, it means obtaining the driver, then using it to insert/select some data?

2) How does this 'code update' interact with the Addon API (https://github.com/engineyard/services-docs/blob/master/API.textile)? I couldn't see any place for the Provider to suggest client libraries, not client code examples. Not even textual documentation

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

This documentation link may help: https://addons.engineyard.com/docs

The "Update Code" step is designed to guide the user through whatever changes they will need to make to their app in order to use the Add-on. As you guessed, this means adding libraries and making code changes to reference any variables your Add-on exposes.

There is no interaction with the Add-on API during this step, it is purely a place to put instructions/documentation for the user. As an Engine Yard partner you can manage the text they see in this step by logging in to the Partner Portal.

Comment: Thanks very much for the fast and useful reply :)